# Fundamental group of product is the product of two fundamental groups (Is my solution ok?)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that there is a similar question, but I want to ask if my solution is ok, or if I should change something or failed totally.

$Y,\tilde{Y}$ are topological spaces.
I have to show that the fundamental group of their product spaces is
$$\Pi_1(Y\times\tilde{Y})=\Pi_1(Y)\oplus\Pi_1(\tilde{Y})$$
and the direct product $\oplus$ is defined as $A\oplus B=\{(a,b)|a\in A,b\in B\}$ with a group structure $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,b_1,b_2)$.
My Proof:?
I name the product topology $W=Y\times\tilde{Y}$. There is a fundamental group for $W$.
$$\Pi_1(W)=\{[f_w]\}$$
$$f_w:S^1\rightarrow W=Y\times\tilde{Y}=\{(y,\tilde{y})|y\in Y,\tilde{y}\in\tilde{Y}\}$$
$$f_w(x)=w=(y,\tilde{y})=(f_{w_1}(x),f_{w_2}(x))$$
$f_w$ has to be continuous because of the fundamental group. It follows that $f_{w_1},f_{w_2}$ have to be continuous because if either $f_{w_1}$ or $f_{w_2}$ is not continuous, $f_w$ is not continuous in one of its components and so $f_w$ wouldn't be continuous.
Now i look at the group structure of $\Pi_1(W)$.

1. Unit element: $$f_w(x)=const=(f_{w_1}(x)=const,f_{w_2}(x)=const)$$
2. composition: $$f_w\circ g_w=h_w=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
   f_w(2t)&=((f_{w_1}(2t),f_{w_2}(2t)) & t\leq1/2\\
   g_w(2t-1)&=((g_{w_1}(2t-1),g_{w_2}(2t-1)) & t>1/2
   \end{array}\right.$$
   Wich is: $$h_w=(h_{w_1},h_{w_2})=(f_{w_1}g_{w_1},f_{w_2}g_{w_2})$$
3. inverse element:
   $$f_w^{-1}=f_w(1-t)=(f_{w_1}(1-t),f_{w_2}(1-t))=(f_{w_1}^{-1},f_{w_2}^{-1})$$
   We know that $\Pi_1(W)$ has to have this group structure, and we see that the components $f_{w_1},f_{w_2}$ fulfill the group for a fundamental group too. So they both have a fundamental group $\Pi_1(Y), \Pi_1(\tilde{Y})$.
   We also see that by looking at the components of $f_w$ the structure, mentioned at the beginning was automatically build because of the group of the fundamental group. So we see that $$\Pi_1(Y\times\tilde{Y})=\Pi_1(Y)\oplus\Pi_1(\tilde{Y})$$ with $A\oplus B=\{(a,b)|a\in A,b\in B\}$ with a group structure $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,b_1,b_2)$ is true.

Is this solution okay and understandable?
Thanks in advance, Greeny

Comment: A shortcut would be noticing that the isomorphism $\pi_1(Y\times \tilde{Y})\cong \pi_1(Y)\oplus\pi_1(\tilde{Y})$ is induced by the projections $p_1:Y\times \tilde{Y}\to  Y$ and $p_2:Y\times \tilde{Y}\to  \tilde{Y}$. I guess you looked at the group structure of $\pi_1(W)$ to see that the composition and inverses are respected componentwise, but that follows from the fact that $p_1$ and $p_2$ induce homomorphisms between fundamental groups.

Comment: I saw a solution with projections but I am not sure if I am allowed to use them. We never talked about projections. On the other hand its a math class for physicists so probably I can use whatever I want. But because I am a physicist I am not really used to proof something thats why I am not sure about my solution. Yes, I looked at the group structure and at the components. So, if I understand it correctly, my solution is a bit long but ok and understandable?

Comment: If you have studied how continuous maps induce homomorphism between fundamental groups then you should be able to use it. I think your solution is understandable and ok. It could just be written better.